# Как отписать UITableViewCell от подписки на события при ее деинициализации?

Tags: swift, события, uitableview, ios10

При создании ячейки она подписывается на определенное событие:

```
class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code

        configureNotifications()
    }

    deinit {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self) // ???: брейкпоинт в этой точке никогда не срабатывает
    }

    private func configureNotifications() {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.somethingChanged), name: .somethingChanged, object: nil)
    }

    // ...
}
```

как ее правильно отписать от этого события, в момент, когда ячейка деинициализуется?

Comment: Какую именно задачу Вы хотите решить? NotificationCenter обычно не лучший вариант, кроме некоторых случаев.

Comment: @VAndrJ в этой ячейке находятся кнопки управления плеером. она получается уведомления об изменения статуса плеера (буферизация/плей/пауза/стоп) и об изменении тайминга и, соответственно, перерисовывает кнопки, обновляет слайдер

Comment: Сделайте протокол класса с функциями, унаследуйте протокол для ячейки и реализуйте нужные функции. Затем через делегата вызывайте эти функции.

Comment: @OlegSoloviev обоснуйте плиз почему так? или ячейку мне не отписать от нотификейшенов?

Comment: Я так понимаю, ячейка у Вас переиспользуемая, поэтому deinit не срабатывает. Сделайте тогда глобальный нотификейшн, в классе, который использует ячейку. Но вообще нотификейшн лучше использовать для системных событий, более важных.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделайте управление подпиской/отписыванием в методах делегата `UITableView`.
В `cellForRow` подписываете ячейку на `.somethingChanged`, а в `didEndDisplaying` отписывайте.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didEndDisplaying cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // Отписываете нужную ячейку, removeObserver
}
```